# When receiving a void** type as a function parameter, the data in the memory area of ​the other variable is changed

Tags: c, pointers, void

I was testing the linked list examples in the "Mastering Algorithms with C (By Kyle Loudon)"

In the example, there was an error in the operation of the function using the void** parameter. The operation error is as below code.

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myswap(void **val1, void **val2)
{
    void **val3;
    *val3 = *val1;
    *val1 = *val2;
    *val2 = *val3;
}

int main()
{
    int val1 = 10;
    int val2 = 20;

    printf("%d, %d\n", val1, val2);
    myswap((void **)&val1, (void **)&val2);
    printf("%d, %d\n", val1, val2);

    return 0;
}
```

result:

```
10, 20
0, 10 <- must be 20, 10
```

This seems to be an error caused by the difference between the size of the variable and the size of the pointer. This can be solved by using a long variable instead of an int variable or by creating a padding variable between the two variables in main().
(I use a 64bit system. So, the size of pointers and long types is 64 bits.)

However, I want to know how to solve it without modifying the variables, structures, and functions of the already written examples. if it is possible.

If anyone knows about this issue, please help

Comment: `"If anyone knows about this issue, please help"` Many books on programming (and algorithms) contain code examples that have been mangled (or possibly never tested.) It's not deliberate, but it happens. That's why publishers often include a web address for "errata" (reported errors in the printed versions.)

Comment: The problem is not that there are errors in the example code. So.. I can't find it in the errata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built with `gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0`, your `myswap` function throws a segmentation fault when dereferencing `val3` that is not initialized (cf. `*val3 = *val1` statement).

If `myswap`'s goal is to make `val1` points on what `val2` pointed to (and the opposite), then the code should be:

```c
void myswap(void **val1, void **val2)
{
    void *tmp;
    tmp = *val1;
    *val1 = *val2;
    *val2 = tmp;
}
```

This way, your code prints the expected `10, 20` and `20, 10` messages.
However, it still ends with a "`*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated`" and `abort (core dumped)` error messages.
This is due to the wrong way of passing `val1` and `val2` arguments to `myswap` function.

The `myswap` function considers `val1` (resp. `val2`) as a double pointer variable, something that point to a `void *` address (*itself pointing to something else*).
In the `main` context, `&val1` is something that points to an `int` variable, and not a `void *` content!
So when `myswap` runs a `*val1 = ...` operation, it gets problematic if `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(void*)` are different (which is the case on x86_64 architecture).

So, there are 3 things you could do:

- Use the `intptr_t` (from `stddint.h`) instead of `int`, because `intptr_t` has the same size as `void *`.

  ```c
  int main()
  {
      intptr_t val1 = 10;
      intptr_t val2 = 20;

      printf("%ld, %ld\n", (signed long)val1, (signed long)val2);
      myswap((void **)&val1, (void **)&val2);
      printf("%ld, %ld\n", (signed long)val1, (signed long)val2);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  But this won't work for non-integer variables (i.e. `struct`, `float`...), where you cannot guarantee that variable size is the same as `void *`
- Use intermediate pointers, and switching those:

  ```c
  int main()
  {
      int val1 = 10;
      int val2 = 20;
      int * ptr1 = &val1;
      int * ptr2 = &val2;

      printf("%d, %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);
      myswap((void **)&ptr1, (void **)&ptr2);
      printf("%d, %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);

      return 0;
  }
  ```

  But this keep `val1` and `val2` variables unchanged, which might not be what you want.
- Use `memcpy` and `sizeof`, as [@0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/0) is suggesting.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the limitations of what I was thinking about. I have a better understanding of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. You cant dereference void  pointers. It is a GCC extension and underlying type is unsigned char. To get the integer you need pointer of the correct type.
2. You need a pointer to pass a pointer to it. In my example I use ***compound literal***

```
void myswap(void **val1, void **val2)
{
    int val3;
    int **i1 = (int **)val1;
    int **i2 = (int **)val2;
    val3 = **i1;
    **i1 = **i2;
    **i2 = val3;
}

int main()
{
    int val1 = 10;
    int val2 = 20;

    printf("%d, %d\n", val1, val2);
    myswap(&(void *){&val1}, &(void *){&val2});
    printf("%d, %d\n", val1, val2);

    return 0;
}
```

You do need double pointers at all. If you tried to create universal swap function:

```
void myswap(void *val1, void *val2, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char val3[size];
    memcpy(val3, val1, size);
    memcpy(val1, val2, size);
    memcpy(val2, val3, size);
}

int main(void)
{
    int val1 = 10;
    int val2 = 20;
    double d1 = 1.0;
    double d2 = 2.0;

    printf("%d, %d\n", val1, val2);
    myswap(&val1, &val2, sizeof(val1));
    printf("%d, %d\n\n", val1, val2);

    printf("%f, %f\n", d1, d2);
    myswap(&d1, &d2, sizeof(d1));
    printf("%f, %f\n", d1, d2);

    return 0;
}
```

You can swap any objects with it. Arrays, structs, unions etc etc.

Comment: Note that `unsigned char val3[size];` declares a VLA.  There are some benighted compilers stuck in the last century that do not support VLAs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what I wanted was not to modify the function to fit a specific data type, or to use a library function.

Comment: @JGD so write you worn memcpy wich is a trivial task